# How to add array values in PHP?

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I want to add array elements price and tax amounts and I have some thing like below for adding.

```
'price': '{$item['price']}',
'tax': '{$item['tax_amount']}',
```

here i want to add price (price) amount and Tax amount (tax_amount), can anyone please tell me how do i add these two.

Comment: Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getFinalPrice())

should bring up the price with the tax if that´s what you are looking for

Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), 2)

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getFinalPrice())
```

should bring up the price with the tax if that´s what you are looking for

```
Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), 2)
```